# reloading the current component (with (click)) if the routerlink active is the same of component actual

Tags: angular

I want that when I click on the link, it takes me to the `"/" route`, this works.

```
<a routerLink="/">Login</a>
```

but if I am already on the `"/"` route, I would like the current component that it represents to be recharged. In other words, if I'm on the `"/"` path and I click on this tag `<a>` I would like the view to be reloaded. how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the same route and try to re-navigate to it, by default angular *doesn't* re-route you again. This is mainly done for performance reasons. (IMO, which makes sense).

Instead if you want to achieve the same functionality, you can call the `ngOnInit()`/method that does the loading of data for the same component.

.html

```
<a routerLink="/" (click)="reloadData()">Reload</a>
```

.ts

```
reloadData() {
   this.ngOnInit();
   // or another method that loads data for the component
   // this.loadData();
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you *may* not want to re-navigate to *all* pages that you are currently on. So this would be specific from component to component based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your root `NgModule` decorator like:

```
@NgModule({
    ......
    imports: [
        .....,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' }),
        ......
    ],
    ......
})
export class AppModule { 
    .......
}
```

Comment: great, how should I import "RouterModule"?

Comment: @yavg You would have already imported it or else you wouldn't have been able to use `routerLink` directive in the anchor tag. Check you AppModule. You would already have an import statement like: `import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';`